# How can I deploy my Spring Boot backend to Render without Docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, deployment

How to deploy spring boot backend to render without using docker

i have react-js as my frontend (which i want to deploy on render)

and java spring boot as my backend(that i am trying to deploy to render)

and my DB MYSQL (that i already deployed on AWS RDS)

i looked for tutorials on on how to deploy my backend to render but all of them use docker...

could not find a proper tutorial for deploying to render without docker..

*i prefer using render to host my frontend and backend cause its free and i am more familiar with it

and ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.